# loop/Iteration in xml with XSLT

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, xpath

I have an xml like shown below ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<recConfig>
    <drecipe>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>BREAD </name>
        <description>           </description>
        <accesslevel>  operator </accesslevel>  
            <parameter>     
            <parameterValue>    test1</parameterValue>
            <parameterValue>    test2</parameterValue>
            <parameterValue>    test3</parameterValue>
        </parameter>

    </drecipe>

</recConfig>
```

i want to transfer it to op like shown below by xslt
OP NEEDED:

```
('2','operator', 'test1')
('2','operator','test2')
('2','operator','test3')
```

I am able to generate until

```
('2','operator')
('2','operator')
('2','operator')
```

I am doing something wrong, i have my xslt below, I am really new to XSLT and Xpath any guidance is  much appreciated

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/recConfig">

    <xsl:for-each select="drecipe">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
        <xsl:variable name="accesslevel" select="accesslevel" />
        <xsl:for-each select="parameter/*">
        <xsl:variable name="parameterValue" select="parameterValue" />
            <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>

            <xsl:for-each select="$id | $accesslevel  | $parameterValue">
                <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>   
            <xsl:text>)&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>   
  </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I suppose this part should iterate through every parameter child node

```
<xsl:for-each select="parameter/*">
```

And this part to read every parameter value into a variable parameterValue

```
        <xsl:variable name="parameterValue" select="parameterValue" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing XSLT, try to stick to "template-match" (functional) and forgo the use of for-each (procedural)

As per your question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parameterValue">
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(../../id/text())'/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(../../accesslevel/text())'/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(text())'/>
    <xsl:text>)&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs the desired:

(2,operator,test1)

(2,operator,test2)

(2,operator,test3)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Marvin , yes it definitely helps.